# call_user_func with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: php

I've got this right now:

`call_user_func(array($controller, $action), $params);`

How can I split apart the `$params` array so that I can call a method with however many params there are, like `controller->action($params[0], $params[1]);` if there's two items, or if there's more than that maybe `controller->action($params[0], $params[1], $params[2]);`

Comment: You know that there's a *See also* section in most manual pages. If you find something that doesn't quite do what you want, check the items there. It's very useful to find alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead, it does just what you want:

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $action), $params);
```

Comment: Gee, do you know Matthew? That was *easy*.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't know him... I'm confused: What do you mean? Are you saying I shouldn't have answered such a simple question?

Comment: You aren't confused. It doesn't matter, but the answer seems a bit preordained. It was just so easy and specific. It seems a little... too easy. You know how it goes.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Ah, true enough.

Comment: ... in spite of myself, I somehow make progress.